# Accessing a ViewController's subview that's added on the storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin, storyboard

Please see the image below for a storyboard visual.  I have a ViewController called StudioViewController (It's labeled ViewController on the storyboard).  And I have a UIScrollView that's called CanvasViewController (the thing to the right of the view controller that actually sits on top of the View Controller).  I want to be able to access the CanvasViewController in the StudioViewController class, how do I do that?  Because I created it in the storyboard here, I dont' seem to have a variable that allows me to access the CanvasViewController... Should I create it in code instead, or is there some obvious way to access it that I'm completely missing?

Thanks

[image: Storyboard visual]

******** UPDATE *********

The question has been answered in the comments below by rdelmar:

Comment: It looks like you have a segue between StudioViewController and CanvasViewController, so you can get a reference to CanvasViewController with  segue.destinationViewController in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Is there another way to do this?  Maybe through accessing the ContainerView or something.  It tried looking for a ContainerView's subView that could be casted to my CanvasViewController but couldn't find one.  I'm just curious if overriding the PrepareForSegue is the proper way to do it or if there is another designed way.  Maybe via a storyboard ID or something?

Comment: Sure, you can also access it from the parent view controller through its childViewControllers property. If you only have the one child, then it would be childViewControllers.firstObject. But using prepareForSegue is a proper way to do it. You can't access a controller through its storyboard id, that's only used to instantiate a new one (which you don't want to do in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a shared variable in the app delegate.  This is not very secure but I have resulted to this when I can't access a child or parent due to page transitions.